# Pester Testdrive does not exists

Tags: powershell, pester

I'm trying to create a test for a custom file-management-powershell function using Pesters TestDrive.
However, I'm not getting it running in any way, always receiving the error that TestDrive does not exists.

Even with the example from the documentation: https://pester.dev/docs/usage/testdrive

I created a file "pester.tests.ps1" with only the example in it:

```
function Add-Footer($path, $footer) {
    Add-Content $path -Value $footer
}

Describe "Add-Footer" {
    $testPath = "TestDrive:\test.txt"
    Set-Content $testPath -value "my test text."
    Add-Footer $testPath "-Footer"
    $result = Get-Content $testPath

    It "adds a footer" {
        (-join $result) | Should -Be "my test text.-Footer"
    }
}
```

The error appearing:

```
Starting discovery in 1 files. Set-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'TestDrive' does not exist. At ...\pester.tests.ps1:7 char:5
+     Set-Content $testPath -value "my test text."
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TestDrive:String) [Set-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand   Add-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'TestDrive' does not exist. At ...\pester.tests.ps1:2 char:5
+     Add-Content $path -Value $footer
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TestDrive:String) [Add-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand   Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'TestDrive' does not exist. At ...\pester.tests.ps1:9 char:15
+     $result = Get-Content $testPath
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TestDrive:String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand   
Discovery finished in 46ms. [-] Add-Footer.adds a footer 10ms (8ms|2ms)  Expected strings to be the same, but they were different.  Expected length: 20  Actual length:   0  Strings differ at index 0.  Expected: 'my test text.-Footer'  But was:  ''  at (-join $result) | Should -Be "my test text.-Footer", ...\pester.tests.ps1:12  at <ScriptBlock>, ...\pester.tests.ps1:12 Tests completed in 152ms Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0 NotRun: 0
```

Am I forgetting something? Are there other prerequisites? I already updated both Pester and Powershell.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty terrible documentation. It says it creates that PSDrive but doesn't say when or how it should. There is nothing saying how to use their example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pester v5 was recently released and it was quite a significant change for how Pester operates, with tests being interpreted in advance. As a result there's some breaking changes for how you have to structure your test one of which being that setup for your tests needs to be done via a `beforeall` or `beforeeach` block.

As such, this rewrite of your example works:

```bsh
function Add-Footer($path, $footer) {
    Add-Content $path -Value $footer
}

Describe "Add-Footer" {

    BeforeAll {
        $testPath = "TestDrive:\test.txt"
        Set-Content $testPath -value "my test text."
    }
    
    It "adds a footer" {
        Add-Footer $testPath "-Footer"
        $result = Get-Content $testPath
        (-join $result) | Should -Be "my test text.-Footer"
    }
}
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/1645) about how Pester v5 impacts TestDrive and i've just added a note to it to call out the fact the documentation example for it no longer works.